# Array Structure Transformation

Tags: php, arrays

i need to transform my array structure from

```
[0=>['a'=>'aa'],1=>['a'=>'bb']]
```

to `['aa','bb']`

Does PHP has some function to handle this?
i mean, i can do it with `foreach`, but is there any dedicated function to solve this since i need it often.
thankyou.

Comment: thankyou, this is very helpful,
do i need to remove this thread or just leave as it?

Comment: I recommend removing the question, because the answer is Read The Manual.  A list of php functions and their abilities are available across the web.  This question shows insufficient research prior to asking for help.

Comment: Somebody gave an answer so accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$array = array_map(function($value){
    return $value['a'];
}, $array);

// or
$array = array_column($array, 'a');
```

Obviously use `array_column()` is easier, but if you want to return multiple or do something at same times, that should be use `array_map()`:

```
$array = array_map(function($value){
    return [
        $value['a'],
        $value['b'],
        $value['c'],
    ];
}, $array);
```

Comment: Might explain why to use one over the other.